# Tsconfig include relative path

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsconfig

I have tsconfig like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".'
  }
  "include": ["**/*.ts", "../additionalDirectory/**/*.ts"]
}
```

I would like to include additional directory ts files to be transpiled in my main project too.
But unfortunately, include don't work well with relative paths ('../'). And it is not seeing them.
I have a monorepo and just want to share some files across my apps.

How should I handle it?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Please give a try using the files property.

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true
},
"files": [
    "core.ts",

],
 "include": ["**/*.ts", "../additionalDirectory/**/*.ts"]
```

}

The "files" property takes a list of relative or absolute file paths.

Comment: Not true, relative paths can't go outside baseUrl. Tired  "files": ["../testDir/testFile.ts"],  and it is not working. BTW. I would prefer to include whole directories instead of separate files.